# Hot deploy com Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

voltei a trabalhar em uma empresa de desenvolvimento e estou com uma certa dificuldade e impaciência com o `Netbeans` e `Jboss`, levando em consideração que eu trabalhei na empresa de dev anterior com `Eclipse` e `Tomcat` e o processo era mais simples...

E por sugestão de uma pessoa fora da empresa me disse q é possível se trabalhar com processo onde se altera arquivos do projeto como arquivos de página, `Java` etc sem necessidade de dar `clean e build`.

A máquina que uso é boa mas toda hora que eu precisar alterar um arquivo `Java` e precisar dar um `clean e build` no `Netbeans`.

O projeto é feito usando `Struts 1`, `Jboss 4.0.1` e `Netbeans 8.2`.

Resumindo, tem como configurar para eu não precisar parar toda hora o servidor e dar o `clean and build` para alterar arquivos no projeto.

Answer (score 1):

**Faz tempo que não toco em JBoss, e não sei se o seu projeto é em Maven ou Ant, então a minha resposta será bem genérica.**

A princípio, é necessário configurar o seu projeto da seguinte maneira:

1. Escolher servidor JBoss (localizado na categoria *Run*)
2. Habilitar **Deploy on Save**

Depois de configurado, a rotina é apenas clicar o botão **Run**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O seu uso do JBoss pode precisar de configurações adicionais, ou possuir outros impedimentos, sugiro tentar as soluções de [Hot deploy of JSF pages in NetBeans to JBoss standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840900/hot-deploy-of-jsf-pages-in-netbeans-to-jboss-standalone).

Comment: Bom dia, como estou usando a versão 4 do `JBoss` acredito que a versão não de suporte a essa alteraçã, para marcar o checkbox "Deploy on Save"

Comment: Configurei o JBoss, e até consegui executar do jeito que expliquei. Inicialmente, roda corretamente, mas depois o NetBeans ignora qualquer alteração. O release dessa versão do JBoss foi a 13 anos atrás, não seria melhor atualizar o seu sistema para funcionar no WildFly?

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho como atualizar